# Minimizes the total time of 2 processors using max flow or min cut

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, max-flow, ford-fulkerson

This is a question from CSE521: Design and Analysis of Algorithms I

> **Question:**
> In this problem we investigate a two-processor assignment of program modules.
> Assume that there are *n* program modules indexed 1, 2, . . . , *n* and two processors A and B. If program module *i* is executed on one processor and program module *j* on the other then the time for interprocessor communication is *cij* ≥ 0. We assume that *cij = cji*. The processors have different speeds so that program module *i* takes time *Ai* on processor *A* and *Bi* on processor *B*.
> The problem is to find an assignment of the program modules to processors that minimizes the total time.
> Reduce this problem to the max flow or the min cut problem. Argue briefly that your reduction is correct.
>
> **An example to demonstrate the question:**
> Table: time cost on processors, *n*=4
>
> ```
>  i  1  2  3  4    
> Ai  6  5 10  4     
> Bi  4 10  3  8
> ```
>
> *cij* = { c(1,2)=5, c(2,3)=6, c(2,4)=2, c(3,4)=1 }
> and the rest have 0 communication time cost
>
> One way to assign the modules to the two processors is
> assigning 1 to *A*, 2 to *A*, 3 to *A*, 4 to *B*
> and the total time cost = A1+A2+A3+B4+c24+c34 = 6+5+10+8+2+1
>
> We want to minimize the total time cost.

**This is my solution:**

let G=(V,E) V={p1, p2, v1,...,vn}, and E={(p1,vi),(vi,p2): i=1..n}U{(vi,vj): cij}. p1 and p2 are the source and sink.

For i=1..n, the weight for edge (p1,vi) is Ai and Bi for (vi, p2). The weight for (vi, vj) is cij=cji.

And then I'm stocked. 
I think the min-cut that cut the graph G into two vertex sets might be the answer.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: can you explain what is the interprocessor communication and what role does it has in this problem ? I don't see how it's relevant here.

Comment: @AloisChristen I added an example. Does that help?  Thanks.

Comment: You seem to be summing all the costs, not matter which processors are assigned which tasks.  Seems strange.  Suppose I assign task1 to processor A and task2 to processor B, I would guess that task1 would finish after 6 time units and task2 after 10, for a total duration 10, but if I assign both tasks to  A they will take 11 or 14 if both on processor B.  What is the point of having two processors if they cannot run concurrently?

Comment: @ravenspoint The question ask to minimize the total time, not the elapsed time. This is not a computer organization problem, but an algorithm problem.

Comment: If indeed total time rather than elapsed, then the question is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the objective is to minimize total time rather than elapsed:

- Assign every task to its most efficient processor.
- Check for every task pair that incur a communications cost because they have been assigned different processors.  If the "total time" would be reduced by assigning them to the same processor, then do so.

( I cannot imagine any scenario where this 'optimization' would have any utility in the real world. )